# SQL Server (WINCC) does not exist

Tags: plc, siemens, wincc

I'm really in trouble having Wincc RT Professional running on my computer. It has consistently come with an error "Compilation not possible. the "WinCC" SQL instance is either not running or not available" anytime I compile it. I searched that it dues to SQL server (WINCC) is not running so I was gonna enable it in Sql server configuration manager but it didn't have such thing like that in the list of SQL Server services. How can I install it manually or make Wincc Pro run successfully? I'm using TIA Portal V14 that worked well with Wincc RT Advanced and the SIMATIC WinCC Runtime Professional has also installed formerly. Hope this description enough and clear for you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error has been reported a number of times on the Siemens forums.  Unfortunately, it seems every time the forum users stop short of saying what they did to fix it (or they didn't fix it)...

As you may have guessed, the backbone of WinCC RT Professional is a Microsoft SQL Server database, although what flavor and version of SQL they embed in their product, I'm not sure.

Your installation has gone bad in some way.  Sorry that's not a helpful description, but it's hard to tell why without further information, so here are some fault finding steps I would take.

If you haven't done so already, have a quick scan of [forum](https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf/us/en/) to see if you can find a quick fix.

If you were never, ever able to compile with this installation, can I suggest the following as general fault-finding:
A. if a working installation on another machine is available, compare the installs as much as possible to find out what's different.  You might find the compatibility tool useful for this: [compatibility tool](https://support.industry.siemens.com/kompatool/pages/main/index.jsf?sitc=wwdfi10002)
B. If (A) is not possible, perform a fresh installation on a different machine *without any other siemens software*, and try to compile.
C. if (B) works, you might have a software conflict.  It happens.  I thought that the installers for the different flavors of WinCC check for this before installing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I looked into all your suggestions and realized that the same version of TIA installed on other machines doesn't run into my problem at all. After comparison, I found that WinCC Runtime  Professional Simulation is not installed yet on mine. How can I supplement it? It seems to accompany by another installation cause I've not found anyone on the Internet and these machine owners didn't remember installing them separately as well. Looking forward to having your help.

Comment: I don't think lacking the simulation component is going to stop you compiling, but it's probably a symptom of another problem.  I think you need to uninstall and then reinstall.  I've only installed WinCC Professional once recently.  Not sure what options to tick but I think any combination should at least allow you to compile.  Run installer as admin, take note of any errors or issues that come up during install - check log files generated and Event Viewer.  If you don't find anything fishy then all I can suggest is rebuild the machine starting with WinCC Prof and add other software after

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your advice. I'm just concerned about my drive space. It's going to be full with just a few Gb remaining. The reinstalling will account for more space (my experience said that) than now and that'll affect machine performance. That's why any solution of fixing is my priority at first. Anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your SQL service is started, as shown in the picture below

[image]

Comment: i am sorry，I am a Chinese people  and my English is not good。

Comment: Thanks for your time. This service does even not exist in mine. I tried to reinstall or any possible way but useless.

Comment: you do not have these services , so your sql server is not fully install .maybe you need rebuild your system and reinstall wincc software